# Spark with flintrock on EC2: ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: apache-spark

I used Flintrock to install hadoop (with Spark) on Amazon EC2.

The MapReduce works fine, and I installed Yarn, but I am having difficulties with spark (both with spark-submit, as well as with Zeppelin), it gives me a connection error. I have 1 master node and 3 others. I found the private IP address of the master node and set that for Spark.

Below is the output from Zeppelin:

Did I mess up with the IP addresses, or do I need to open a TCP port or so?

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o120.partitions.
: java.net.ConnectException: Call From ip-172-31-19-18.ec2.internal/172.31.19.18 to ip-172-31-19-18.ec2.internal:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused;
```

My yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>172.31.34.90</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Any other config files or logs I can provide?

```
flintrock, version 2.0.0
spark: 3.1.2
hd: 3.2.0
OS: ami-0b5eea76982371e91 # Amazon Linux 2 5.10
```

Comment: Magically it works after logging out and in. Don't know if it helped, but I did run $HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager

Answer (score 0):

Magically it works after logging out and in. Don't know if it helped, but I did run $HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager